# Steam - libGL.so.1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, steam, opengl

I have tried all of the solutions I can find on here to fix this.

I have removed and installed various combinations of the libGL.so.1 for 32 bit and I have it now where the GUI for steam will come up but it won't run the whole thing.

I did a clean install after I installed my GTX 1060 the other day. Steam was working just fine before that, so I know it's not my setup. However maybe installing the nvidia drivers before steam was the problem?

Here is the output when I try to run steam:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Failed to load steamui.so - dlerror(): libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
[2017-06-16 01:59:01] Startup - updater built Jun  8 2017 04:33:02
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2017-06-16 01:59:01] Checking for update on startup
[2017-06-16 01:59:01] Checking for available updates...
[2017-06-16 01:59:02] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1496897923, installed version 1496897923
[2017-06-16 01:59:02] Nothing to do
[2017-06-16 01:59:02] Verifying installation...
[2017-06-16 01:59:02] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2017-06-16 01:59:02] Verification complete
[2017-06-16 01:59:06] Shutdown
```

All I want to do is get my steam up and running again. I hope someone out there has some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

libGL.so.1 is part of the mesa-package.
You have to (re)-install the package using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

If this wont fix the problem. you can create a config for steam to
load the right libs:

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf
```

content should point to the libs

```
/usr/lib32
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
```

...dont forget to apply the new config

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I may have created the steam.conf wrong. What should the file contain explicitly? I'm still getting the same error.  Steam now will not even start a GUI session. Just gives: 
`Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
`

Comment: I forgot to mention, if it's relevant, the steam version that I am using is the one from the steam website. It seemed like that was a newer version of steam so I went with that. I know it works, because I had it running on the same machine before.